# Does numpy linalg.eig() block multiprocessing?

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing

I am trying to run a function in parallel with the multiprocessing module. However there seems to be a deadlock. It seems to be due to the numpys:

`np.linalg.eig`

If I uncomment this function my code runs as expected. Does this occur due to some low level blas/laplack implementation? And is there a way to circumvent this?

EDIT:
Ok, this took a while. This is the minimum I could reduce my code, while keeping the problem. The model class makes a neural net. This NN is modified in a loop and then the parallel functions are called. The model isn't needed for the evaluation of these functions. However the code only finishes if I:

- reduce the models parameters (i.e. setting `N_MAX = 100`)
- don't call `perturbate()`
- don't call `np.linal.eig()` in `build_single_bridge()`

```

```
import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.multiprocessing as mp


class Model(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, n_in, n_out, hidden_layers=1, hidden_neurons=(64,)):
        """
        Make a multi-layer-perceptron.

        :param n_in: (int) Input of the model.
        :param n_out: (int) Output of the model.
        :param hidden_layers: (int) No. of hidden layers.
        :param hidden_neurons: (tpl) Hidden neuron per hidden layer.
        """
        super(Model, self).__init__()
        self.n_in = n_in
        self.n_out = n_out
        self.hidden_layers = hidden_layers
        self.hidden_neurons = hidden_neurons
        self.dense_in = nn.Linear(n_in, hidden_neurons[0])
        self.hidden = []
        for i in range(hidden_layers):
            exec(f"self.hidden_{i + 1} = nn.Linear(hidden_neurons[{i}], hidden_neurons[{i}])")
            exec(f"self.hidden.append(self.hidden_{i + 1})")
        self.dense_out = nn.Linear(hidden_neurons[-1], n_out)

    def es_params(self):
        """
        The parameters that will be trained by ES.
        :return: (list)
        """
        return [(k, v) for k, v in zip(self.state_dict().keys(),
                                       self.state_dict().values())]


def perturbate(model, seed, sigma=0.05):
    """
    Create two new models. And modify both in opposite direction.

    :param model: (Model)
    :param seed: (int)
    :param sigma: (flt)
    :return: [Model, Model]
    """
    import copy
    new_model = copy.deepcopy(model)
    anti_model = copy.deepcopy(model)
    np.random.seed(seed)

    for (k, v), (anti_k, anti_v) in zip(new_model.es_params(),
                                        anti_model.es_params()):

        # draw from a gaussian distribution eps ~phi(mean, std)
        eps = np.random.normal(0, 1, v.size())
        noise = torch.from_numpy(sigma * eps).float()
        v += noise
        anti_v -= noise

    return [new_model, anti_model]


def evaluate(queue, seed):

    fitness = build_single_bridge()

    queue.put([fitness])

def build_single_bridge():
    a = np.zeros((320, 320))
    np.linalg.eig(a)

    return 1


if __name__ == "__main__":

    N_MAX = 200
    m = Model(3, N_MAX, 1, (N_MAX // 2,))


for i in range(1):
    queue = mp.Queue()

    all_seeds, all_models = [], []
    for j in range(3):
        perturbate(m, 1, 0.05)

    p = mp.Process(target=evaluate,
                   args=(queue, 1))

    p.start()
    p.join()

    print(queue.get())
    print("END")
```

```

Comment: I wouldn't expect so, so we need the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Ok, I'll try to reproduce it in a small snippet.